# Determining the Big O Order for a Non-Standard Recurrence Relation

Tags: analysis, asymptotics, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity

**Question:**

Find the best possible order for $ T(n) $, for sufficiently large values of $ n $.

$ T(n) = 2T\left(\frac{n}{2}+\sqrt{n}\right)+T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+1 $

**My try:**

Here is my attempt at finding the solution using induction to prove $T(n) \le cn^{\log_{2 - \varepsilon}(3)} + b$:

$
\begin{align*}
\varepsilon & > 0 \\\\
T(n) & \leq 3T \left( \frac{n}{2} + \sqrt{n} \right) + 1 \\\\
& \leq 3T \left( \frac{n}{2 - \varepsilon} \right) + 1 \quad \text{(For n )} \\\\
T(n) & \leq 3c \left( \frac{n}{2 - \varepsilon} \right)^{\log_2(3)} + 3b + 1 \\\\
& = \frac{3cn^{\log_{2 - \varepsilon}(3)}}{(2 - \varepsilon)^{\log_{2 - \varepsilon}(3)}} + 3b + 1 \\\\
T(n) & \leq cn^{\log_2(3)} + 3b + 1 \leq cn^{\log_2(3)} + b \quad \text{if } b < -\frac{1}{2} \\\\
\varepsilon & > 0 \Rightarrow T(n) \in O \left( n^{\log_{2 - \varepsilon}(3)} \right)
\end{align*}
$

**What I can't find:**

Provide a proof that setting $\varepsilon = 0$ is permissible.

$ T(n) = 2T\left(\frac{n}{2}+\sqrt{n}\right)+T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+1 \in O \left( n^{\log_{2}(3)} \right)$

Comment: You might try the Ansatz $T=An^a\ln^bn$.

Comment: Didn't work. @J.G.

Comment: Given

$$
\cases{
a(n) = (n^2+1)^2-(n^2-1)^2\\
b(n) = 2n(n+1)\\
c(n) = a(n)/2
}
$$

the recurrence support for

$$
T(n) = 2T\left(\frac{n}{2}+\sqrt{n}\right)+T\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)+1
$$

is $\{n,\frac{n}{2}+\sqrt{n},\frac{n}{2}\}$ and this support is feasible for $n$ such that

$$
\{n,\frac{n}{2}+\sqrt{n},\frac{n}{2}\} = \{a(n),b(n),c(n)\}
$$

and in this support, the recurrence is void.